# In which order should I send callback() & notify waiters?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class through which I offer some services asynchronously(the same calls can also be made synchronously). When requested an object of this class(say operator) starts the operation in a different thread. Other objects can register to the notifications of operator object so that when the operation ends OperationEnded() method is called on this objects. Other objects may also wait completion of this operation by calling Wait() on the operator object.

The code at the end of the operation is pretty much as follows:

```
_opEndedMutex.lock();
_thereIsOngoingOp = false;
_opEndedCondition.notify_all();
_opEndedMutex.unlock();

//no more call after notification
m_spNotificationManager->OperationEnded();
```

and the wait() function is as follows:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(_opEndedMutex);
while(_thereIsOngoingOp)
{
    _opEndedCondition.wait(_opEndedMutex);
}
```

The problem is about resource management. This is a C++ class so when the end of operation is detected the user of this class may delete the operator object(the destructor waits completion if there is any active operation). The end of the operation may either be detected by waiting or accepting notification. So if I call _opEndedCondition.notify_all() first and the user deletes the operator object it may crash while trying to call OperationEnded() because m_spNotificationManager is deleted. And if choose to call OperationEnded() first and the user deletes the operator object during this call then it may crash while trying to reach _opEndedMutex, _thereIsOngoingOp and _opEndedCondition.

The first thing that comes my to mind as a solution is to protect the two calls with a new mutex. This did not seem pretty because I cannot foresee what may happen if a new mutex is introduced and if in an OperationEnded() notification the user syncronously starts a new operation. I am also not sure how to use a new mutex in the wait() method.

note1: This API is both used in our own company's and other companies' applications. So I cannot get rid of either of the synchronization mechanisms.

note2: I've modified the original code, variable and method names so there may be typos, but the idea should be clear.

edit1:

The operator objects stay in a shared library generated through a factory and then exposed to the outside world through an interface.
so typical lifetime of an operator object would be as :

```
IOperator * op = factory:getNewOperator();
//perform operations with op
op->Release() //this one goes and deletes the op object
```

Also note that operator objects are reusable. Client code can make a new operator object use it several times and delete it at the end.

Comment: You need it in C++ only or Shall i post some code related to C#?

Comment: The real problem lies in the resource management so C# would not be too much relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem by counting asynchronous operations.

When a new operator object is constructed we add its pointer to a reference count table. 
When this object starts an asynchronous operation we increment the reference count and when 
an operation ends the we decrement the reference count.

When release is called on an object if the reference count is 0 we delete it. If it is greater than 0 
we keep the pointer in a soonToBeDeletables vector. so when an operation ends if the reference count is 0 and if the operator object that performs the operation is in the sooToBeDeletables vector we delete the Operator object.

When an asynchronous operation end we first signal the condition variable and then made the OperationEnded() call. But probably the reverse would also work.

With this approach the data races are now solved and the deletions are deterministic. We did not require a background worker thread that would wake up some time later and make the deletions. Determinism was required because when several objects are consequently constructed, used(synchronously) and deleted then for some time several objects would reside in the memory at the same time which would be undesired in memory limited(mobile) systems.

Lesson learned: Try to provide only a single notification mechanism when possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few solutions to this:

- You can specialize your operation object from [std::enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this). This would mean that in the  client code, you no longer delete the object, but set a std::shared_ptr to nullptr, and don't care when the object is actually deleted.
- You can implement limited garbage collection, on a timer delay: When you receive the `OperationEnded()` notification in client code, you take the pointer and place it on a queue, along with a timestamp for when the object was added. The queue would then have an active object that wakes on a timer, takes the current time, and if the timestamp is (let's say) at least five seconds older than the current time, deletes it.
- You can allocate and de-allocate the operation class using an [object pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html). When an object is no longer used, it is not actually deleted, but placed as a free (recycled) object in the pool. The object would actually be deleted when the pool is destroyed, after you finish your processing.
- You can create a life-time-manager for your object, that would delete your operation object and then send the notification.
- You can make your 'OperationEnded' function call `delete this;` at the end; Then, you would implement client code to simply set the pointer to NULL when receiving the notification; Such a solution is brittle though and it's possible that with your implementation, this just shifts the problem to a different piece of code.
- Finally, you can implement a custom combination of all these.

Comment: Thanks for several good ideas, these gave me a good direction. I also edited the question to give more info about the API. Evaluating your offers one by one.

1- I cannot control all the client codes(there are so many) so any solution on that side is a no go. distributing the API as a shared_ptr would be good but any change here is not acceptable - I am also not a big fan of distributing a version of boost with my API. This in fact would not be enough by itself we should also keep the shred_ptr ourselves to prevent early deletion, and set it to null at some point which is the original problem

Comment: 2- This is a good direction but still there would be a race here. I can accept this as a solution if this deletion is done through some synchronization means instead of some delay. I think this is the best candidate.

3- Object pool would be good. But this still leaves the problem of when exactly I should delete the object without a race/crash.

4- Objects are reusable. So this is not acceptable. Sorry I will add this info to the question. 

5- I cannot modify client code. OperationEnded() is overwritten in the client side.

Comment: 6- I think second offer with a combination of some thread safety measures would be good.

Comment: For solution 2, you would need to keep a list of pointers to be deleted. This list would need to be synchronized when you add poiners (and timestamps) to it (to be deleted), when you read the pointers and timestamps from the list, and when you remove them from the list (if a given timeout has passed). The delay mechanism is a way to avoid conflicts on delete (i.e. if a thread finishes (on average) one second after calling `OperationEnded()`, you should delete added pointers after ten seconds or so.

Comment: The operator objects are reusable. Some of them may possible live for months(the library is also used in server machines). So putting delays and hoping to avoid conflicts does not fit this library.

Comment: Total number of objects in process does not exceed some hundreds. So when Release() called on an object I can check if there is active operation on that object and if so I can keep it in a list. Then maybe periodically check if the objects on the list are still being used and delete when appropriate. Bu I just do not want to introduce non-deterministic behavior on this library, meaning that some Release() calls will immediately decrease memory footprint and some won't.